# Using class based on variable passed

Tags: php, laravel

I have a handful of classes:

```
 App\Services\class1Service;
 App\Services\class2Service;
 etc.
```

when a user clicks a button, they pass a variable to a function I have.  I am trying to get that function to call a given class. anything I try below adds an extra slash to the call.

I tried the Reflection Class inherent to php

```
    function doStuff($pass){
           //$pass = "Class1";
        $var = "$pass".Service::".$pass."()";
        $a = (new \ReflectionClass("App\Services\\".$var))->newInstance();
    }
```

and just straight:

```
  function doStuff(){
           //$pass = "Class1";
      $var = "$pass".Service::".$pass."()";
      $a = "\App\Service\\".$var();
  }
```

both end up with:

```
"message": "Class App\\Services\\Class1Service::Class1() does not exist",
```

in my debug.

Where is the extra \ coming from?

I would expect:

```
App\Services\Class1Service::Class1()
```

to be called

Comment: the extra slashes there are just how it is being displayed in that error message (wouldn't be valid JSON if they weren't escaped), it doesn't mean you have those extra slashes in your string

Answer (score 1):

the  \  has a special meaning in string Laravel
for example \n means a new line ...

to tell Laravel that you want \ itself without any special meaning you should simply duplicate it:

```
        $model =  "\\App\\Services\\" . $pass;
        $modelInstance= new $model;
```